# extra characters after close brace

Tags: linux, oracle, hammerdb

When I use [hammerDB](http://www.hammerdb.com/) to test the Oracle 12c database TPM, sometimes I  get this error，

> extra characters after close-brace。

I have 3000 warehouses and 100 virtual users.  I only get this error sometimes, not every run.

Basic information

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
  Production
- HammerDB-2.23

How can I avoid this error?[image]

Comment: Don't put extra characters after close-brace.

Comment: thanks for you answer,but this is no close-brace in my operations for hammerDB, every time in hammerDB, i modify the oracle servicename,password and virtual users ,then create,finally run,why sometimes this error will happen.is hammerDB software's bug?

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

The driver script in the script editor window is posted to the virtual users to be run and is parsed by the TCL interpreter loaded by the virtual users. This error indicates that the script has been corrupted. Use the driver script load icon in the treeview to refresh the script to one without introduced errors. Also note that despite error catching it may be possible to have characters such as comments and wildcards remain uncaught in the servicename and password that could result in a parsing error, however in this case this is not as likely as the error is not received all of the time. There is also a newer release - HammerDB 3.0 using an updated TCL interpreter 8.6.8.